# Facebook curiosity, what javascript framework are they using?

Tags: javascript, facebook

wondering if some of you know what javascript framework facebook is using ?

Thanks

Comment: You can check it yourself. Just look at the code. That's the beauty of JavaScript.

Comment: yeah but the whole is packed but no mention of any copyright.

Comment: @RageZ: you could use a beautifer (http://jsbeautifier.org/), which is the opposite of a minifier. That explains the "beauty" portion of my comment :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like they're using their own as there aren't any YUI/jQuery script references and it looks like standard DOM scripting.

Answer (score 5):

Its anyones guess.

First of all, their core services are based on [Thrift](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/) which Facebook has made opensource; also, they have their own library based on JavaScript. They are probably incorporating a lot of standard DOM scripting (but obfuscated) code in and above the user-space.

Based upon [presentations](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack) you can get a feel of their organizational layout and how they might implement a lot of their functionality.

There was a leak circa 2007 of the source code if you can find it, if it is still present, but of course: this is the internet.

We might actually get our hands on current source should [Facebook comply with their court order.](http://www.realgeek.com/facebook-ordered-again-to-reveal-their-entire-source-code/)

Answer (score 2):

There is also "Javelin", as revealed at the open sourcing of PHAbricator, a internal tool made to control source code internally (git viewer) + tasks and other things.

Here is the documentation: http://phabricator.com/docs/javelin/index.html

You can also look for the source (by accessing phabricator) and take a look of some particularities of how facebook develop their applications.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked myself that question before. It is very hard to tell though, because they have everything obfuscated. Who knows what they are doing? It is their private property, their servers are private from the world.

I do know some things. They have polluted the global name space a lot with modules that don't start with dojo, YAHOO, or jQuery.

Apparently they have their own JavaScript library called FBJS, however, I don't know the extent of their use of it in their own site.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS

Answer (score 1):

None. For large projects the use of a framework usually limits capabilities so it would be a waste of time to extend it instead of building a custom framework. However, Facebook engineers took this farther by modifying the actual PHP/javascript language to suit their needs. Here is a presentation on facebook's software stack: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack

Answer (score 1):

I heard React js framweork used by facebook .

Previously this is not open source , now they released as Opensource

Here is Git hub link :

[Facebook react js](http://facebook.github.io/react/)